# Стилизация select и Opera

Tags: select, css

Здравствуйте
Помогите со стилизацией select'a, проблема в браузере Opera со стрелкою самого select'a. В Chrome и FF отображается правильно.

Код тут: http://jsfiddle.net/dBuLG/2/

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опера не поддерживает appearance. См. [CSS3 Browser support](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp). Если приглядеться повнимательнее, то можно заметить, что select никуда не делся, а просто вы отрезали стрелку шириной div'а и сделали ему overflow:hidden. При этом бэкграунд div'а остался под селектом и его естественно не видно.

Либо стилизуйте скриптом (для jquery полно плагинов), либо не использовать селект вообще (самый неудобный элемент управления), либо оставьте дефолтное отображение... чистый css тут бессилен.